# Click a link and invoke another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Ok so I have this html code:

```
<h1 class="left" data-target="newest">Newest</h1>
............
<h1 class="left" data-target="topRated">Top Rated</h1>
....
```

which clicking on the h1 tag does a jquery function, now I have this html links

```
        <li>
            <a href="">Newest</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Top Rated</a>
        </li>
```

I need to do, somehow, that when clicking `<a href="">Newest</a>` in the list or `<a href="">Top Rated</a>`, to be like if you were clicking on the `h1` tag. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to be able to click on an h1, and have it really click the related anchor.

```
$("h1").click(function(){
    var textTarget = $(this).text();
    $("a").filter(function(i, val) { return $(val).text === textTarget; }).click();
});
```

Ideally though, if you could do:

```
<li>
    <a href="" data-target="newest">Newest</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="" data-target="toprated">Top Rated</a>
</li>
```

then the script would simply be:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("h1[data-target='" + $(this).data("target") + "'").click();
});
```

Comment: well I was meaning when clicking the A to act like clicking h1 (h1 click already has its click function), but I guess that setting a instead of h1 and h1 instead of a will do

Comment: hahaha, it's exactly the other way arround... clicking A, will invoke click on h1... don't worry I understand your solution

Comment: @w0rldart - ha.  I thought your original comment was telling me that I was backward, that's why I changed it :)  No worries though, you said you understand the answer, so that's what matters.

Answer (score 1):

Change your links to:

```
<a href="#" class="h1-selector" data-action="newest">Newest</a>
```

Then, you just need to trigger a click on the `H1`:

```
$('a.h1-selector').click(function(){
    $('h1[data-target="'+$(this).data('action')+'"]').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var href = $(this).text();//Newest
  $('h1[data-target=' + href + ']').trigger('click');
});
```